# Removing last two digits

Tags: sql-server

If I  have 12345678, 1234567, 123456 in a table as a column and using sql I want to create a new column that will have new numbers that removed the last two digits of each number. The new column will have 123456, 12345,1234.

Would someone help in writing this code in Microsoft sql environment

Comment: What do you want to do with shorter numbers, like 123, 12, and 1?

Comment: yes something like that...

Comment: Something like what?

Answer (score 6):

It's just a simple integer division.

So select (123456/100).

But that only valid is the column is integer type.

The example provided is big. If the column is integer then using a simple case logic is suffice. First check if the value is bigger than 99 then divide by 100, if not use what it is.

```
Declare @field_name;
Set @field_name = 123456;

Select (case when @field_name > 99 then (@field_name/100) Else @field_name);
```

change field name to any column you wish and adjust the query to target table.

Rather than using convert or cast , integer divide provide less cpu cycle because of dedicated math block inside the cpu. When using convert or cast you have many more cpu cycle because it will also include memory operation.

Comment: Why the downvote? Dividing by 100 seems valid. I don't think the case for < 100 is necessary though, the question is how to remove the two last digits.

Comment: Hhmmm. Seems like and dislike come first before trying the solution. Or just too lazy to write  the code itself.

Comment: Some people just like to dislike :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your filed type is int
You can use this code to remove last two digits. Instead of using variable you can use your field name.

```
declare @field_name int
set @field_name = 12345678

SELECT convert(int,substring(CONVERT(varchar(10), @field_name),1,len(CONVERT(varchar(10), @field_name))-2))
```